# Multiple file upload over https hangs with blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: jquery-file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I've downloaded the master files from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and run the demo on IIS 8.5 and IIS 10.0. Everything is working fine on http. If I try to upload multiple files on https the upload progress (overall progress bar and every single file's progress bar) hangs after a while (After ~2MB total upload). The upload progress goes on with long delays. 5 files (Total ~4 MB) take 7 mins to upload.

**maxAllowedContentLength** and **maxRequestLength** values are set as **max**.

As I said everything looks like OK over http. The problem occurs on https. What kind of IIS setting should I do to fix it?

Comment: I found what the problem is. It's about HTTP/2 Protocol. I had to disable it. Then worked fine. You can try it with `chrome --disable-http2`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will fix your issue
Just refer the URL
   http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm

Comment: It's not about the large file size. I've already set up the file size limits in web.config. I can upload a single 2 GB file without any problem. The problem occurs when i try to upload more than 1 file over totally 2 MB on https.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out how to fix this bug without Setting google chrome.

And I use this method. Just adding

`sequentialUploads : true`

in fileupload setting section like this

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
      sequentialUploads: true,
      ....
});
```